# Obter somente primeiro item de uma sublista VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Bom, estou tentando retornar apenas o primeiro item do sub-array mas não estou conseguindo, o método natural `{{ itens[0].name }}` não funciona:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="teste">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="conteudos in conteudo">{{conteudos.nome}}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="itens in conteudos.contribuidores">{{itens[0].name}}</li>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: "#teste",
      data: {
        conteudo: [
          {
            "nome": "Zé",
            "idade": 29,
            "contribuidores": [
              {
                "name": "Jane Doe",
                "phone": "888-555-1212",
                "relationship": "spouse"
              },
              {
                "name": "Justin Doe",
                "phone": "877-123-1212",
                "relationship": "parent"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A questão aí é que você está fazendo **v-for** a mais, quando faz **`v-for="conteudos in conteudo"`** a partir daí você já tem tudo que precisa em **conteudos**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#teste",
  data: {
    conteudo: [{
      "nome": "Zé",
      "idade": 29,
      "contribuidores": [{
          "name": "Jane Doe",
          "phone": "888-555-1212",
          "relationship": "spouse"
        },
        {
          "name": "Justin Doe",
          "phone": "877-123-1212",
          "relationship": "parent"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="teste">
  <ul v-for="conteudos in conteudo">
    <li>Nome: {{conteudos.nome}} - Idade: {{conteudos.idade}}
      <ul>
        <li>Nome: {{conteudos.contribuidores[0].name}}</li>
        <li>Tel: {{conteudos.contribuidores[0].phone}}</li>
        <li>Parentesco: {{conteudos.contribuidores[0].relationship}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Trazendo todos por exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#teste",
  data: {
    conteudo: [{
      "nome": "Zé",
      "idade": 29,
      "contribuidores": [{
          "name": "Jane Doe",
          "phone": "888-555-1212",
          "relationship": "spouse"
        },
        {
          "name": "Justin Doe",
          "phone": "877-123-1212",
          "relationship": "parent"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="teste">
  <ul v-for="conteudos in conteudo">
    <li>Nome: {{conteudos.nome}} - Idade: {{conteudos.idade}}
      <ul v-for="dados in conteudos.contribuidores">
        <li>Nome: {{dados.name}}</li>
        <li>Tel: {{dados.phone}}</li>
        <li>Parentesco: {{dados.relationship}}</li> <br>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso, **itens** não é uma lista. Ele representa um unico objeto da uma lista **conteudos.contribuidores**.

Tente trocar o **{{itens[0].name}}** por **{{conteudos.contribuidores[0].name}}**

Comment: itens é uma lista de objetos já que o `for`está direcionado à **contribuidores**

Comment: Pelo que vejo no código, itens representa um objeto da lista contribuidores.

Comment: Iteração 1: itens = {
                "name": "Jane Doe",
                "phone": "888-555-1212",
                "relationship": "spouse"
              },

Iteração 2: itens = {
                "name": "Justin Doe",
                "phone": "877-123-1212",
                "relationship": "parent"
}

Comment: logo, **itens[0]** é o primeiro objeto, e eu quero o **name** desse objeto

Comment: Itens[0] não existe neste escopo. 
itens ta representando um objeto contribuidores.
ex:  var itens = contribuidores[0]

Comment: Tente usar este comando: **{{conteudos.contribuidores[0].name}}**

Comment: Não funcionou não